# Using SCP in Golang in Windows to copy remote files in remote unix host

Tags: linux, windows, go, scp

Is needed to copy remote files in a linux server to a windows local server and I want to know if is possible to use golang (with standard lib or not and the process will be runnning on windows) to accomplish this task, or even the way could be to call another process like winscp.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this problem:

- Use library to execute SCP protocol. There isn't any standard library in golang for SCP protocol. But you can use [this](http://godoc.org/github.com/laher/scp-go/scp) library for SCP protocol.
- Use OS binary to execute SCP protocol. But please keep in mind that, in this case your program can only run on machine, which has this particular OS binary installed.

Comment: That go-scp package doesn't appear to be particularly well vetted, and it uses an old and unmaintained version of the go ssh package which will be taken offline completely this month. Using the local `scp` binary does limit to hosts with openssh installed, but it isn't going to make your program any slower.

Comment: @JimB, Agreed with first point, I will edit the answer with better alternative. But about second point, using the local `scp` binary will technically slow down program a bit because you need to fork new process every time you want to use `scp` protocol, which is an expensive operation. Besides, if program wants to monitor the progress for a very large file, then it needs to monitor `stdout` of `scp`. This also requires parsing of the `stdout`, which is also time consuming task. So, using `scp` binary will somewhat slow down your program.

Comment: While it does add time, I highly doubt the extra <4ms the fork and wait adds (still probably <10ms if you have to page in the scp binary) has a real effect for most people. When you count in the ssh protocol, encryption and network overhead, forking the remote scp process, and not to mention *transferring files over the network*, the extra few milliseconds don't account for much.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for the all information of your valuable comments. But there are in go robust alternatives for copy files or synchronize folder between distinct OS out there?

Comment: @Bera: you could use the sftp protocol with something like github.com/pkg/sftp, or you could just exec winscp like you suggested. If you want more recommendations, the mailing list or IRC are probably better choices, as that's off-topic here.

Comment: @JimB. Agreed. Edited the answer to reflect that.